# Websocket Upgrade Required 426

Tags: python, node.js, websocket

I was run my program where use websocket connection. Before, my program was run correctly but today I get error message websocket connection closed uncleanly, upgrade required 426. In client I use autobahn twisted version 15.4.0 and in server I use ws websocket in node js.
Please give me some advise.
Thankyou.

This is my client code:

```
##WebSocket Class
class MyClientProtocol (WebSocketClientProtocol):
    def onConnect(self, response):
        status = "Server connected: {0}".format(response.peer)
        logData(status)

    def onOpen(self):
        status ="WebSocket connection open."
        logData (status)

        def SentData ():
            select()

            if (numberOfData==0): #jika data kosong koneksi terputus
                # if there is no data, connection will closed
                self.sendClose()

            else:
                self.sendMessage (dataSent.encode('utf8')) #send data if file not empty

        SentData ()

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if isBinary:
            print("Binary message received: {0} bytes".format(len(payload)))
        else:
            # if server sent ack connection will close
            if (payload.decode('utf8')=="ok"):
                print("Text message received")
                status="data sent"
                logData(status)
                dataNew[:]=[]

                update()
                # get time while sent
                #p=subprocess.Popen("date", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
                #output= str(p.communicate())
                #logData(output)

                self.sendClose ()

            else:
            # if server sent nack, data will resend
                self.sendMessage(dataSent.encode('utf8'))

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        status ="WebSocket connection closed code [{}]: {}".format(code,reason)
        logData (status)
        self.factory.reactor.callLater (int(interval),webSocketConnect)#send data every 10 seconds


#websocket connection function
def webSocketConnect ():
    factory = WebSocketClientFactory (u"wss://node-imamabdul-2.c9.io:8080", debug=False)
    factory.protocol = MyClientProtocol

    reactor.connectTCP("node-imamabdul-2.c9.io",8080, factory)

#SIGINT
def SIGINT_CustomEventHandler(num, frame):
    k={1:"SIGHUP", 2:"SIGINT"}
    status="Recieved signal - " + k[num]
    logData(status)
    if frame is not None:
        status="SIGINT at %s:%s"%(frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_lineno)
        logData(status)
    status="In SIGINT Custom Handler Shutting Down ..."
    logData (status)
    if num == 2:
        #status= "shutting down ...."
        exitFlag=True
        reactor.stop()


## main 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    readID()

    conn = sqlite3.connect(vcspath+'vcsdb2.db')
    cur= conn.cursor()
    create ()    
    ## global variables
    #os.system("hwclock -w -f /dev/rtc1")
    exitFlag = False
    Data =[]
    DataStatus=False 
    #makeDir ()

    webSocketConnect()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, SIGINT_CustomEventHandler)
    reactor.run()
```

This is my server code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: process.env.PORT });

port = process.env.PORT;
console.log("PORT :" + port);
wss.on('connection', function connection(wss) {
  console.log("connection opened" + wss.listeners());

  wss.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log("connection has message: " + message)
    var fs = require('fs');
    var timestamp = new Date().toString('hex')
    fs.appendFile('fromclient.csv',"['"+timestamp+"']"+' ' + message+'\n')

    wss.send(message);

  });
  wss.on('close', function closeSocket() {
    console.log("connection closed");
  });
  wss.on('error', function socketError() {
    console.log("connection has error");
  });
});
```

Comment: Try connecting to your server using javascript from your browser... can you connect or do you get an error? (try isolating the issue - is it a server issue or a client issue)?

Comment: I can connect to my server. If I connect with atubahn twisted v11 it can connect too.

Comment: I'm sorry, Imam, I didn't understand your answer... When you try to connect with autobahn v11 you CAN connect (working)? With raw websockets in javascript (no library) you cannot connect (not working)? and when you try with autobahn v15 you cannot connect (not working)?

Comment: Can you post some code? edit your question and add the code you use to connect to your server.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw you updated the answer in your comment... from your answer I understand it's a client issue...

Comment: sorry, When I try to connect with autobahn v11 I can connect to my server. Actually I didn't try in javascript. I try with websocket.org and use demo test to connect my server.

Comment: I think my problem comes when I try to connect with GSM Modem. But, when I connect with LAN connection I didn't get that problem.

Comment: Are you using `wss` for one and `ws` for another? The issue in Autobahn 15.4.0 seems to be related to SSL connections (`wss`) only... Either way, please edit your question and post your connection code, so people can look at it and help solve the issue if they can.

Comment: @Myst I already edit my question. Please give me some advise

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect what I learned from your code. As I understand it, you are experiencing a bug in Autobahn 15.4.0 that was fixed 9 days ago. You need to change your Autobahn version.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using an encrypted websockets connection, here (in your python code):

```
#websocket connection function
def webSocketConnect ():
    factory = WebSocketClientFactory (u"wss://node-imamabdul-2.c9.io:8080", debug=False)
    factory.protocol = MyClientProtocol

    reactor.connectTCP("node-imamabdul-2.c9.io",8080, factory)
```

Because you are using Autobahn 15.4.0 with `wss`, you are experiencing [the issue (bug) that exists in Autobahn version 15.4.0](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/issues/535).

The issue was fixed 9 days ago.

You need to either update Autobahn to a version after the fix (the really new version, if it was released) or downgrade Autobahn to a version before the issue (the bug) was introduce.

Another option is to use `ws` instead of `wss` - this means your connection will NOT be encrypted and this isn't as recommended.

Good luck!

Comment: I think my problem comes when I try to connect with GSM Modem. But, when I connect with LAN connection I didn't get that problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. How to upgrade/downgrade my autobahn?
But when I use LAN/eth0 connection I didn't get that error message.

Comment: I think that you don't have SSL setup for your local server... so when you are connection to the local server, you use `ws` and not `wss`... or maybe the Autobahn bug is funny this way... As for upgrade, I don't know. How did you install version 15.4.0? I see version 0.10.9 ... maybe keep using the old version until an official release?